# Polling error using Coinpayments in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptocurrency, coinpayments-api

Code works fine, but when executed after few seconds it starts consoling
error message 'Polling error'.

I tried searching the term but nothing came up,

Any help is appreciated.

```
var Coinpayments = require('coinpayments');
var options = {
  key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  autoIpn: 'true',
  ipnTime: 'false'
}
var client = new Coinpayments(options);

client.getBasicInfo(function (error, result) {
  error ? console.log(error) :
    console.log(result);
});

client.createTransaction({ 'currency1': 'USD', 'currency2': 'LTCT', 'amount': 1 }, function (error, result) {
  error ? console.log(error) : console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, issue was I needed to give all permission to API used in CoinPayments.

The operation I was using which needed some permission from API

which they didn't mentioned in error message.

Comment: from where do you change that ?

Comment: If i remember correctly, in the merchant tools. i don't have access to account right now.